Intermittent Stack Overflow website connectivity issues
I'm trying to browse stackoverflow.com through my company's internet, and often the website fails to open.
We reviewed the company's firewall but there are no rules to prevent from reaching the website.
We have reason to believe that the problem occurs when connecting to the internet using specific ISPs, since the same problem has occurred for an employee that uses the same ISP for his home internet and his mobile phone.
I tried changing the Domain Name System (DNS) configuration to use Google's DNS, but that didn't help.
I also noticed on a DNS check website when testing for stackoverflow.com that the DNS is not propagated properly in some remote areas. I'm currently located in Jordan.
Any insights about this problem and how it can be solved without changing the ISP? I have been using another ISP at home and there aren't any problems with it regarding to stackoverflow.com.

Highly doubt SE can do anything to bypass ISP restrictions. But perhaps the issue is not SO itself but rather some other domain being used, e.g. Google, or sstatic which the ISP might block.

Also, looks like it's some government policy in Jordan to throttle internet, so not really random. See this for example. Off topic here of course, but that's likely true and the cause for what you experience. (site they don't like will be sporadically blocked and unblocked on different ISPs, on-and-off.)
